# How to reuse console used by current process

Tags: winapi, fasm

I want the following assembly to write `Hello World!` in the current console. Currently it is working but writes `Hello World!` into a new console window. I have tried removing the `invoke AllocConsole` statement but it does not write anything and exits with code `-1073741819`. What is the simplest way to use the existing console window when the executable is called from the terminal?

```
include 'win64ax.inc'

.data
    tex     TCHAR   'Hello World!'
    dummy   rd      1

.code
    start:
        ; Don't want to allocate new console. How to use existing??
        invoke  AllocConsole
        invoke  WriteConsole, <invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE>, tex, 12, dummy, 0
        invoke  Sleep, 1000

.end start
```

Comment: I have never used the fasm compiler. In some of the examples that I searched for using `WriteConsole`, they all assigned a new console. This makes me wonder whether the console of the fasm compiler does not support winapi output.

Comment: Try [`AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole) and don't `AllocConsole` if it succeeds.

Comment: @dxiv I think your on the right line. How would I get the parent process id though ..?

Comment: As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole) (and spelled out in the previous comment), use the symbolic constant `ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS`. That will *"use the console of the parent of the current process"*.

Comment: @IInspectable my bad didn't see that in the docs. Although with `invoke  AttachConsole, ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS`, fasm fails with `error: undefined symbol 'ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS'`

Comment: In that case simply push the value (also documented), a `(DWORD)-1`, i.e. `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: @IInspectable Hmm now getting `undefined symbol 'AttachConsole'`. I think it may be a issue with fasm as `AttachConsole` is not mentioned in `KERNEL32.INC` (unlike `AllocConsole` and `WriteConsole`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to make a console app instead of a GUI app? Then just define [`format PE64 console`](https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#2.4.2) at the top of the file (instead of the `format PE64 GUI` which `win64ax.inc` defaults to). With this, you can just remove the call to `AllocConsole`, because a console app automatically gets allocated a console by the operating system, or the console from the parent process if that is a console process.

`-1073741819` is [`NTSTATUS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55) `0xC0000005 STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`, which you get because your function does not return (`ret`) or call `ExitProcess`. Note that `.code` inserts a `sub rsp, 8` to align the stack, so you need to insert `add rsp, 8` before the return of `start` to balance this out. Lastly, if you use `ret`, you may want to set the exit code in `rax` to `0`.

Full code:

```
format PE64 console
include 'win64ax.inc'

.data
    tex     TCHAR   'Hello World!'

.code
    start:
        invoke  WriteConsole, <invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE>, tex, 12, NULL, NULL
        xor eax,eax
        add rsp, 8
        ret

.end start
```

Result:

```
> .\print.exe
Hello World!
```